# Are there any solutions for server-side rendering of Dojo Charts?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am looking for a way to render a Dojo Chart on the server, maybe similar to a HighCharts solution ([highcharts-serverside-export](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export)). Did anyone succeed in running dojox.gfx on the server side?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a specific example that I can point to, but I've heard of people having luck doing this by using things like http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ or http://phantomjs.org/ - it's not a full answer but it may point you in a useful direction.